# AdvancedDataGrid LockedRowCount not working

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, advanceddatagrid

I am trying to lock  the 1st row in my ADG. This 1st row is the SummaryRow. When I set the lockedRowCount property to 1, it still does not freeze the 1st row. I have tried with different numbers, but it is still not working. In fact, when I try to trace the value for lockedRowCount, it traces it as 0. Can anyone provide suggestion on how to do this with the lockedRowCount property or if you can provide me with another workaround, that'll be great.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

i think u r using hierarchical data as dataprovider, u cannot lock advanceddatagrid if the data provider is of type HierarchicalData